# why this code doesn't print "20"?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, heap-memory, stack-memory

```
void fun(int* x){
    x=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *x = 20;
}

int main(){
    int y=31;
    fun(&y);
    printf(%d,y);
}
```

Why this code succeed to compile anyway?

Comment: it was compiled on Eclipse
I see the problem on line:
   x=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

why this program didn't crashed at runtime?

Comment: Because C gives you enough rope to hang yourself.

Comment: delete `x=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));`, `%d` --> `"%d\n"`

Comment: Don't cast the result of malloc in C, and use sizeof(*x) instead of sizeof(int).

Comment: You're passing the address of a stack variable, allocate some heap memory, and set the value in there to 20, you're never modifying the stack variable. Instead, you're leaking memory

Comment: Don't lie. `printf(%d,y);` compiled? Hang me instead.

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example._

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code syntactically, so it compiles.

The address of `y` is passed to the function. the pointer `x` in the function which holds the address of `y`, is overridden by an address of valid memory allocated by malloc. An int is written there and not into `y` as the value of the pointer was changed. Then the function returns (the allocated memory in `fun` does 'leak').

The value of `y` in the main stays unchanged.

The behavior of this program is defined.

Comment: @user3781974 You have a couple typos in the code in your question. Please fix them.

Answer (score 3):

hey you  are passing a copy of address of the variable y which is pushed on the stack. You just manipulate the pointer (At the location where the pointer was pushed) by assigning the address returned by `malloc` and copy a value of 20 into that address by

```
*x = 20
```

which doesn't have impact on variable in `main` i.e `y`

If you want it to print 20 this may help

```
void fun(int** x){
    *x=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    **x = 20;
}

int main(){
    int *y;
    fun(&y);
    printf("%d",*y);
}
```

Comment: The example you gave is wrong as memory is allocated to copy of `y` and   `y` remians _uninitialized_ in `main` . So basically it has **_undefined behaviour_** .

Comment: Why on earth would you use double indirection? Why not `void fun(int *x) { *x = 20; }` and just pass `int y; fun(&y);` in main?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Because the OP is following a dynamic memory allocation example, so the answer is related to the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
x=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));  //x point to a new addr.

*x = 20;  // change value of new pointer
```

delete the line `x=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));`,then it will work .

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you wanted to do is change the address of the variable `y` in the `main` function. You cannot do that by passing the address value of `y` into a function. Because there is simply no assigning operation done on address of `y`. In your example there is no variable (which is basically a pointer) for the address of `y` (forget about assigning).

```
    int* fun(int* x){
        printf("Fun before %p - %d\n", x, *x);
        x = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *x = 20;
        printf("Fun after %p - %d\n", x, *x);
        return x;  // return your new address
   }

   int main(){
       int *y = malloc(sizeof(int));
       *y = 31;
       printf("Main before %p - %d\n", y, *y);
       y = fun(y);  // assign your new address here
       printf("Main after %p - %d\n", y, *y);
       return 0;
   }
```

But above code will do.